# InvalidCastException error with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Below my code. It returns exception "InvalidCastException". And main question is - why?
What is wrong?

Error text:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectListIterator`2[Monopolowy_beta.Gracz,Monopolowy_beta.Gracz]'
>   to type 'Monopolowy_beta.Gracz'.

```
namespace Monopolowy_beta
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Gracz> lista = new List<Gracz> { };
            Gracz g1 = new Gracz();
            Gracz g2 = new Gracz();
            Gracz g3 = new Gracz();
            g2.Id = 3;

            lista.Add(g1);
            lista.Add(g2);
            lista.Add(g3);

            g1 = GraczeTools.UstawAktywnegoGracza(lista, 3);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Error in these lines:
`var docelowy = from item in listagraczy where (item.Id==ID && item.czyAktywny == true) select listagraczy[listagraczy.IndexOf(item) + 1];
                    gracz = (Gracz)docelowy;`

```
namespace Monopolowy_beta
{
    static class GraczeTools
    {

        public static Gracz UstawAktywnegoGracza(List<Gracz> listagraczy, int ID)
        { 
            Gracz gracz = new Gracz();
            if (ID == 4){
                var docelowy = from item in listagraczy where (item.czyAktywny == true && item.Id == 3) select listagraczy[1];
                gracz = (Gracz)docelowy;
            }

            if (ID != 4){
                var docelowy = from item in listagraczy where (item.Id==ID && item.czyAktywny == true) select listagraczy[listagraczy.IndexOf(item) + 1];
                gracz = (Gracz)docelowy;
            }


            return gracz;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var docelowy = from item in listagraczy 
               where (item.czyAktywny == true && item.Id == 3) 
               select listagraczy[1];
```

Let's examine this query. It finds all items which satisfy condition (yes, it will return sequence, not single item) and for each such item, it returns.. second element of `listagraczy` list. Yes, you don't have items, which matched your condition.

I think you should select `item` instead (this a range variable of your query), and apply `FirstOrDefault` to result, because by default query will return `IEnumerable<Gracz>` result.

```
var docelowy = (from item in listagraczy 
                where (item.czyAktywny == true && item.Id == 3) 
                select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which is better to write with fluent API:

```
var docelowy = listagraczy.FirstOrDefault(item => item.czyAktywny && item.Id == 3);
```

Also you can use boolean values directly in conditions (i.e. `item.czyAktywny` instead of `item.czyAktywny == true`).

---

After little refactoring your method should look like

```
public static Gracz UstawAktywnegoGracza(List<Gracz> listagraczy, int ID)
{ 
   return listagraczy
           .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == 3 && (ID != 4 || item.czyAktywny));
}
```

How it works:

You have two conditional blocks in your method `if (ID == 4)` and `if (ID != 4)` (which is actually `if ... else`. Difference is that you are filtering sequence by one more condition in first case - `item.czyAktywny` should be true. In second case this property does not matter. So, you can add one filtering condition instead `(ID != 4 || item.czyAktywny)` - czyAktywny will be verified only if ID equal to 4. Also you don't need to create new `Gracz` object in your method, because you anyway return one from passed list.

Comment: Yeah, those 'number of ways' I referenced in my answer are spelled out in more detail here, and the one-liners are spelled out better than I was going to.  +1, good stuff.

Comment: but last thing - could you explain me what exacly do this part of code? `item => item.Id == 3 && (ID != 4 || item.czyAktywny)`. I know the result and and a litle bit how it works, but if you could describe step by step, I will be grateful.

Comment: i can't edit: especially, why this part is good - how it works? `item.Id == 3 && (ID != 4 || item.czyAktywny)`. There is && - it works like "if not id=3, then go to second part", yes? Or I think wrong?

Comment: @whoah I added an explanaton :) `&&` is `AND` operator. Second part will be checked only if first part is true.

Comment: great, thanks ! now everything is totally clear. Good night ;-)

Comment: but (really) last thing - this function returns first element. What if I need +1(next) element (if ID<4) in list or list[0] (if ID=4)?

Comment: @whoah then query will not be that simple - `if (ID == 4) return listagraczy.First()` and for `(ID < 4)` you should verify which item is returned (it could be last item in list, then you can't just return next. Also you should handle case when `(ID > 4)`

Comment: I use FindIndex with this lamba expression, then short if statement to choose right index in list - now works perfectly. Big thanks for help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `gracz = (Gracz)docelowy;`, use `gracz = docelowy.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement is returning an `IEnumerable<Gracz>`.  So, when you attempt to cast it to `Gracz` directly, the computer doesn't know how to do that and throws the error you're seeing.

There are a number of ways you can handle this situation, but the simplest would be to simply add `FirstOrDefault` to your invocation, giving you

```
gracz = docelowy.FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of what you currently have.  By the way, you'll need to add this to your other `if` statement too - it has the same problem.